# Keying a collection by type

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to have a collection of objects that implement a certain interface, but I'd like to only have one per concrete type within the collection.

```
collection of implementers of dog:
 - instance of dachshund
 - instance of beagle
 - instance of corgi
```

In .NET, there's a "KeyedByTypeCollection".  Does something similar exist in Java in such a way that I could use it on Android?

Thanks!

Comment: I've looked at the docs for the .Net collection and am struggling to imagine why it would be useful (except maybe for singleton factories). What's the reason for using it? Maybe there's something different in Java that serves your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at generics. E.g.:
`List<Dogs> dogList = new ArrayList<Dogs>();`

**EDIT:** to have only unique instances in your collection, you should use `Set<Dogs> dogList = new HashSet<Dogs>();`

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use third-party libraries -- and if you don't care about maintaining order -- [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) seems applicable here.

```
ClassToInstanceMap<Dog> map = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();
map.putInstance(Corgi.class, new Corgi("Spot"));
map.putInstance(Beagle.class, new Beagle("Lady"));
Corgi corgi = map.getInstance(Corgi.class); // no cast required
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: I'd like to keep it as portable as possible.  Especially because I'm considering using my library on Android.  Thanks though :)

Comment: Eh?  Guava's 100% compatible with Android.  Indeed, some of the folks who worked on the Android core libraries work on Guava...

Comment: ...in point of fact, Guava's one of [the most common dependencies](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/guava/google-guava) for Android apps.  But if you're concerned about APK size, [there are ways to address that](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a custom HaspMap that will maintain multiple values with same key,

So, create an simple class that extends HashMap and put values into it.

```
public class MyHashMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> {

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        List<String> current = get(key);
        if (current == null) {
            current = new ArrayList<String>();
            super.put(key, current);
        }
        current.add(value);
    }
}
```

Now, create the instance of MyHashMap and put values into it as below,

```
        MyHashMap hashMap = new MyHashMap();
        hashMap.put("dog", "dachshund");
        hashMap.put("dog", "beagle");
        hashMap.put("dog", "corgi");
        Log.d("output", String.valueOf(hashMap));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{dog=[dachshund, beagle, corgi]}
```

Comment: Neat. I think making this method generic could buy one something.

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you are looking for:
see the comments in codes

```
// two Dog(interface) implementations
        // Beagle, Dachshund implements Interface Dog.
        final Dog d1 = new Beagle();
        final Dog d2 = new Dachshund();

        // here is your collection with type <Dog>
        final Set<Dog> set = new HashSet<Dog>();
        set.add(d1);
        set.add(d2);

        // see output here
        for (final Dog d : set) {
            System.out.println(d.getClass());
        }

        // you can fill them into a map
        final Map<Class, Dog> dogMap = new HashMap<Class, Dog>();
        for (final Dog d : set) {
            // dog instances with same class would be overwritten, so that only one instance per type(class)
            dogMap.put(d.getClass(), d); 
        }
```

the output of system.out.println line would be something like:

```
class test.Beagle
class test.Dachshund
```

Comment: `dogMap.values()` is the desired collection, no need for an additional set. Furthermore, I would add generic parameters to class: `Map<Class<? extends Dog>, Dog>`.